# strace output processing

Tags: python, bash, sed, strace

I am using strace in this way:

```
strace -xf -eopen -o out_configure.log ./configure
strace -xf -eopen -o out_make.log make
```

Then I am getting clear file list with sed:

```
sed -n 's/.*open("\(.*\)".*)\s*=.*/\1/p' out_configure.log out_make.log | sort -u
```

There is an output example:

```bsh
/usr/share/locale-langpack/en.utf8/LC_MESSAGES/gcc-4.6.mo
/usr/share/locale-langpack/en.UTF-8/LC_MESSAGES/gcc-4.6.mo
/usr/share/locale-langpack/en.utf8/LC_MESSAGES/grep.mo
/usr/share/locale-langpack/en.UTF-8/LC_MESSAGES/grep.mo
/usr/share/locale-langpack/en.utf8/LC_MESSAGES/make.mo
/usr/share/locale-langpack/en.UTF-8/LC_MESSAGES/make.mo
/usr/share/locale/locale.alias
/usr/share/misc/magic.mgc
/usr/x86_64-linux-gnu/lib64/libc_r.a
/usr/x86_64-linux-gnu/lib64/libc_r.so
/usr/x86_64-linux-gnu/lib64/libsendfile.a
/usr/x86_64-linux-gnu/lib64/libsendfile.so
/usr/x86_64-linux-gnu/lib64/libtruerand.a
/usr/x86_64-linux-gnu/lib64/libtruerand.so
/usr/x86_64-linux-gnu/lib64/libuuid.a
/usr/x86_64-linux-gnu/lib64/libuuid.so
util.c
util_cfgtree.c
./util_cfgtree.h
util_cfgtree.h
util_cfgtree.i
./util_cfgtree.lo
util_cfgtree.lo
util_cfgtree.loT
util_cfgtree.o
util_cfgtree.s
util_charset.c
./util_charset.h
```

My problem is non-Full name entries (such as "util.c" or "./util_cfgtree.h").
Is there any way to get full names in strace output?

I have wrote this script:

```
#!/usr/bin/python
# coding=UTF8
import subprocess
import os

fileList = []
for dirname, dirnames, filenames in os.walk(os.path.abspath('.')):
    for filename in filenames:
        fileList.append(os.path.join(dirname, filename))

straceProcess = subprocess.Popen("strace -s 1000 -xf -o out_configure.sed.log ./configure".split(), stdout=subprocess.PIPE).communicate()[0]
straceProcess2 = subprocess.Popen("strace -s 1000 -xf -o out_make.sed.log make".split(), stdout=subprocess.PIPE).communicate()[0]


f = open("out_configure.sed.log", "r+")
n = open("out_make.sed.log", "r+")

lines = []
for l in f:
    lines.append(l)
for l in n:
    lines.append(l)

f.close()
n.close()

pids = {}

filesInUse = []
currentDir = os.path.abspath('.')
for line in lines:
    parts = line.split()

if not pids.has_key(parts[0]):
    pids[parts[0]] = currentDir

if parts[1].startswith("clone"):
    pid = parts[parts.__len__() - 1]
    if not pids.has_key(pid):
        pids[pid] = os.path.abspath(pids.get(parts[0]))


elif parts[1].startswith("chdir"):
    if parts[1].split("\"")[1].startswith("/"):
        pids[parts[0]] = os.path.abspath(parts[1].split("\"")[1])

    elif parts[1].split("\"")[1].startswith("."):
        pids[parts[0]] = os.path.abspath(pids.get(pids[parts[0]]) + '/' + parts[1].split("\"")[1])
    else:
        pids[parts[0]] = os.path.abspath(pids.get(parts[0]) + '/' + parts[1].split("\"")[1])

elif parts[1].startswith("open("):
    if parts[1].split("\"")[1].startswith("/"):
        filesInUse.append(os.path.abspath(parts[1].split("\"")[1]))
    elif parts[1].split("\"")[1].startswith("."):
        filesInUse.append(os.path.abspath(pids.get(parts[0]) + '/' + parts[1].split("\"")[1]))
    else:
        filesInUse.append(os.path.abspath(pids.get(parts[0]) + '/' + parts[1].split("\"")[1]))


for l in filesInUse:
    if l in fileList:
        fileList.remove(l)

for l in fileList:
    print  l
```

But my knowledge of Python is very poor.

Are there any mistakes or bad solutions?

Comment: `strace` records the system calls as they are made.  If the program asks for `open("util_charset.c", ...)`, that's the name that will be recorded.  You need to know the current directory of the process to be able to interpret the relative pathnames (including `open("subdir/file.c", ...)`).  For that, you need to know the current directory of the process — both the one at process start and any changes made during the process run.  If you have two directories with, say, the old and the new version of a programs source code, it may be impossible to say from `strace` output which build was traced.

Answer (score 1):

I think in order to do this, you would also need to trace the `chdir()` system calls. Post-processing would be more complicated, and you would probably need to switch to `awk`, `perl`, `python` or something else for the post processing, because you would need to interpret each `chdir()` to track the current working directory as it changes, then, for `open()` calls that are either relative or local (i.e. not a full path), you would need to prepend the current path and make any adjustments for things like `../`, etc.

Answer (score 0):

Those are local files related to the application you are making.

you could parse the list to another file and then look for anything starting with ./ or not starting with / and do a find within script to map the paths.

In the below example I was building apache and those same files appeared in a hidden folder (part of its build process in the server folder)

```
find . -name vhost.o
./server/.libs/vhost.o
./server/vhost.o

ls  server/.libs/
config.o      core_filters.o  eoc_bucket.o    exports.o        libmain.a   listen.o  main.o        protocol.o  request.o     util_cfgtree.o  util_debug.o   util_filter.o  util.o       util_script.o  util_xml.o
connection.o  core.o          error_bucket.o  gen_test_char.o  libmain.la  log.o     mpm_common.o  provider.o  scoreboard.o  util_charset.o  util_ebcdic.o  util_md5.o     util_pcre.o  util_time.o    vhost.o
```

E2A: 
Here is a one liner that does what you need:

```
 command="sed -n 's/.*open(\"\(.*\)\".*)\s*=.*/\1/p' out_configure.log out_make.log | sort -u"; echo "remote: " && echo $command| /bin/sh|grep "^/" ;echo "______________________"; echo "local" && echo $command|/bin/sh|grep -v "^/" |xargs -I {}   find . -name  {} -print
```